# Maven update contents of an EAR file

Tags: maven, maven-2

I have an EAR file which I want to update. I do this in Ant by unzipping the EAR and then the JAR, replacing a few files and then repackaging it.

I am trying the same with Maven but with little success and it is also confusing.

So far I have done

1) installing the EAR file in the local maven repository
2) unpack it 
3) Replace the file I need

Now I am not sure how to get back the new EAR file. Everything is in the repository.

From my understanding, the EAR plugin packs everything in the ejb, war folders and spits out the ear. But since I directly got the EAR file, I do not have any project per se.

Any suggestions on this?

Also is there a good tutorial on Maven?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably perform the following steps, using a "blank" Maven project and assuming the EAR file is already inside a repository (pushed by another project/tool):

- use the [dependency:unpack](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-mojo.html) mojo to get and unpack (inside the /target/ folder of your project) the EAR
- modify the contents
- use the [assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) to repack that EAR file

Then do what you need to do with that new EAR file.

A "blank" Maven project would mean that it will not act as a usual project (compile sources, package output...), but rather serve to manipulate existing artifacts through specific plugins.

Comment: I tried this but have a few more questions. 1) EAR format is not supported in assembly plugin 2) Which maven project no. to use to create this blank project?

Comment: 1) EAR is basically a JAR format, with a different file extension. The purpose of the EAR plugin is to take care of generating a usable EAR file. If you already have one, then zipping is enough. 2) not sure to understand your question. I just mean by blank project a project that is only intended to orchestrate plugins executions, and not represent an artifact (WAR, EAR, JAR...)